# A numeric field from an Oracle query return variable results when zero

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I have this odd behavior on a vb.net application, I make a simple query to an Oracle database using ODP.Net. One of the fields is a simple division but as expected, the result has many decimal values so I apply Oracle's Round function to it in order to bring up to 7 decimal values.

Due the rounding, some very small values actually become zero which is fine, however, in some rows I get the zero value as expected but in another rows the same field shows with a null value instead of zero.

I have dig both vb.net and odp.net but couldn't find an explanation for this. I have tested the query in both Toad and Oracle own SQL Developer, in all the result shows zeroes without issue, but still have the problem in vb.net.

If anyone has any input to this, it will be really appreciated, thank you.

J.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: The problem was from previous data processing within the same transaction which was having uncommitted null values and of course, querying the database using other tools was reading the fields' default values (hence the zeroes). Strangely is, Oracle didn't complain about dividing by null and simply gave null as result.

Comment: dividing by null is not an error.  Any arithmetic operation that includes  null value will return null.